# How to seralize ArcGIS JSON to .Net core object?

Tags: postgresql, arcgis-server, .net, nettopologysuite

I want to get ArcGIS JSON response ([like here](https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Water_Network/FeatureServer/8/query?where=1%3D1&objectIds=&time=&geometry=&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&distance=&units=esriSRUnit_Foot&relationParam=&outFields=*&returnGeometry=true&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=&having=&gdbVersion=&historicMoment=&returnDistinctValues=false&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&returnExtentOnly=false&orderByFields=&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&multipatchOption=xyFootprint&resultOffset=&resultRecordCount=&returnTrueCurves=false&returnExceededLimitFeatures=false&quantizationParameters=&returnCentroid=false&sqlFormat=none&resultType=&featureEncoding=esriDefault&f=pjson)) from server and save it to my database. I am using .Net core and entity framework net topologysuite for CRUD operations database. But I coud not convert the Esri JSON object to .Net object. Is there any tool for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a dynamic object in C#.  I'm taking a guess here that you are using C# as there is no code posted.

I'm doubting you have an  object that exactly matches the ESRI response object, and I doubt you want to take the time to create one. This is what you can use a [dynamic object](https://www.educba.com/c-sharp-dynamic/) for. In .net core you can use the System.Text.Json namespace to Deserialize the response into a dynamic object. This should answer your question...

However, I'm not sure you need to convert this to an object to save to the database. It's JSON, which is just a string. Why can't you just save the JSON string into the database? If you need to use it later you pull that data and Deserialize it into an object.

```
   class Program {
        static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Main(string[] args) {

            string baseUrl = "https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Water_Network/FeatureServer/8/query?where=1%3D1&objectIds=&time=&geometry=&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&distance=&units=esriSRUnit_Foot&relationParam=&outFields=*&returnGeometry=true&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=&having=&gdbVersion=&historicMoment=&returnDistinctValues=false&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&returnExtentOnly=false&orderByFields=&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&multipatchOption=xyFootprint&resultOffset=&resultRecordCount=&returnTrueCurves=false&returnExceededLimitFeatures=false&quantizationParameters=&returnCentroid=false&sqlFormat=none&resultType=&featureEncoding=esriDefault&f=pjson";
            try {
                using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient()) {
                    using (HttpResponseMessage res = await client.GetAsync(baseUrl)) {
                        using (HttpContent content = res.Content) {
                            var data = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                            if (data != null) {
                                // This line will allow you to get a .net object from the JSON
                                var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(data);
                                // Here it's being serialized again to write to the console
                                Console.WriteLine("ESRI Data ------------  {0}", JsonSerializer.Serialize(result));

                            } 
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception:");
                Console.WriteLine(exception);
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

What I often do in these sort of cases is create a class based on a (representative) example of the JSON response (i.e. one that has most or all properties set to a value, rather than null):

- Copy the JSON to the clipboard
- In Visual Studio, add a new class to your project
- Select Edit → Paste special → Paste JSON as classes

You may need to hand-edit some types, because VS will can only do a best guess, based on whatever is in your copied JSON sample. For instance, if a value is `1`, the type might be set to `byte` or `short`, rather then `int`. If you then try to deserialize a value outside the `short` range, your application will throw an exception.

In your specific example, since the geometry is a point, the generated Geometry class will only have `x` and `y` fields, and therefore will not match a line or polygon.

Deserialization is done like this:

```cs
return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<myArcGISClass>(json);
```